# SwiftMailer sender domain not allowed using SMTP Dreamhost?

Tags: php, email, smtp, swiftmailer, dreamhost

I'm trying to send an email using SwiftMailer and SMTP. The SMTP server is a standard Dreamhost setup. I only get the issue when using an email that is not hosted on dreamhost. For example if I use `contact@joescotto.net` as the from email, I will have no problems and the email will send. However, if I use `contactjoescotto@gmail.com` I'll get the following error:

> Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.7.1 Sender domain not allowed. Please read: http://dhurl.org/20b D157 "

My email function is as follows:

```
/**
 * Sends an email
 * @param  string $name    Sender name
 * @param  string $subject Sender subject
 * @param  string $email   Sender email
 * @param  string $message Sender message
 * @return bool            True if sent, otherwise false
 */
public static function sendMessage($name, $subject, $email, $message) {
    // Create and setup the transport
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance($GLOBALS['config']['smtp']['host'], $GLOBALS['config']['smtp']['port'])
        ->setUsername($GLOBALS['config']['smtp']['username'])
        ->setPassword($GLOBALS['config']['smtp']['password']);

    // Create the mailer using your created Transport
    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance($subject)
        ->setFrom([$email => $name])
        ->setTo(['contact@joescotto.net' => 'Joe Scotto'])
        ->setBody($message);

    // Try to send the message
    if (!$mailer->send($message)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Set email timeout cookie
    setcookie("emailTimeout", true, time() + (60 * 5), '/');

    // Return true on sucessful send
    return true;
}
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: Whats the From address ?

Comment: on dreamhost I send email with swift mailer using "sendmail" transport, easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try no-reply@whatever-server-you-are-on & use the reply-to header for the from address?